# Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

First let me apologize for not understanding the answer that is already given to this question and to appeal for patience to those that will say " this has already been answered go read up the answers given". I have combed through this site and read every answer given - but I am still stompped. Here is my entire query and the error that I am getting:

---

```
CREATE DATABASE flghtreservation;

use flghtreservation;

CREATE TABLE Passenger
(
  Fname varchar (20) NOT NULL,
  Lname varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  Passenger_id varchar (6) Not NULL,
  Phone_number varchar (20) NOT NULL,
  Email_address varchar (20) NOT NULL,
  Gender varchar (5) NOT NULL,
  Fopayment varchar (15),
  PRIMARY KEY (Passenger_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Airlines
(
  Airline_name char (30) NOT NULL,
  Airline_no INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Airline_no)
);

CREATE TABLE Airports
(
  Airport_code char (3) NOT NULL,
  Airport_name varchar (50) not null,
  City varchar (20) NOT NULL,
  State varchar (15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Airport_code)
);

CREATE TABLE Routes
(
  Route_no varchar (8) NOT NULL,
  Route_descrip varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Route_no)
);

CREATE TABLE Flights
(
  Flight_no INT NOT NULL,
  Airline_code char (5) NULL,
  Departure_AirportCode char (5) NOT NULL,
  Depature_date date NOT NULL,
  Arrival_AirportCode char (5) Not NULL,
  Arrival_date date not null,
  Price  decimal (5,2),
  Airline_no INT NOT NULL,
  Route_no varchar (8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Flight_no),
  FOREIGN KEY (Airline_no) REFERENCES Airlines(Airline_no),
  FOREIGN KEY (Route_no) REFERENCES Routes(Route_no)
);

CREATE TABLE Fare
(
  Fare_type varchar (3) NOT NULL,
  Fare_descrip varchar (15) NOT NULL,
  Route_no varchar (8) Not nulL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Fare_type),
  FOREIGN KEY (Route_no) REFERENCES Routes(Route_no)
);


CREATE TABLE TicketInfo
(
  Confirmation_no varchar (10) NOT NULL,
  Lname varchar (30) NOT NULL,
  Passenger_id varchar (6) NOT NULL,
  Fare_type varchar (3) NOT NULL,
  Flight_no INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Confirmation_no),
  FOREIGN KEY (Passenger_id) REFERENCES Passenger(Passenger_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (Flight_no) REFERENCES Flights(Flight_no));

insert into Passenger values
("Taylor", "Amanda", 'B0011', '(952)-659-0259', 'AT11@hotmal.com', 'F', "Visa"),
("Smith", "Adam",   'B0012', '(763)-555-0229', 'AS12@gmail.com', 'M', "Master"),
("Jeffries", "Daneil", 'B0013', '(214)-659-7885', 'JD13@yahoo.com', 'M', "Visa"),
("Hassan", "Aisha", 'B0014', '(612)-159-0099', 'AH14@hotmal.com', 'F', "Master"),
("Mohammad", "Nivi", 'B0015', '(204)-541-0201', 'NM15@hotmal.com', 'F', "Visa");


Insert into Airlines values
("Southwest Airlines", 001),
("Delta Airlines", 005),
("American Airlines", 003),
("United Airlines", 004),
("Sun Country", 002);

Insert into Airports values
('ATL', "Hartsfield Jackson Atlanta International", "Atlanta", "Goergia"),
('MSP', "Minneapolis-St Paul International", "Minneapolis", "Minnesota"),
('ORD', "Chicago O’Hare International", "Chicago", "Illinois"),
('LAX', "Los Angeles International", "Los Angeles", "California"),
('JFK', "John F Kennedy International", "New York", "New York"),
('SFO', "San Francisco International", "San Francisco", "California"),
('DFW', "Dallas Fort Worth International", "Dallas-Fort Worth", "Texas"),
('DEN', "Denver International", "Denver", "Colorado"),
('LAS', "McCarran International", "Las Vegas", "Nevada"),
('MCO', "Orlando International", "Orlando", "Florida");

insert into Routes values

('RTE01', "North America Mid West Route"),
('RTE02', "North America North East Route"),
('RTE03', "North America East Coast Route"),
('RTE04', "North America West Coast Route");

Insert into Flights values
(111, "SW", "ATL","2016-08-02", "MSP", "2016-08-20", 321.50, 001, 'RTE01'),
(112, "SW", "ATL","2016-08-03", "MSP", "2016-08-21", 250.50, 001, 'RTE01'),
(511, "DL", "ATL","2016-08-02", "MSP", "2016-08-20", 390.50, 005, 'RTE01'),
(312, "AA", "MSP","2016-09-02", "JFK", "2016-09-14", 467.50, 003, 'RTE02'),
(512, "DL", "MSP","2016-09-02", "JFK", "2016-09-14", 500.50, 005, 'RTE02'),
(411, "UA", "MSP","2016-09-02", "JFK", "2016-09-14", 350.50, 004, 'RTE02'),
(211, "SC", "MSP","2016-09-05", "DFW", "2016-09-20", 400.50, 002, 'RTE03'),
(513, "DL", "MSP","2016-09-05", "DFW", "2016-09-20", 430.50, 005, 'RTE03'),
(414, "UA", "MSP","2016-09-05", "DFW", "2016-09-20", 390.50, 004, 'RTE03'),
(113, "SW", "MSP","2016-09-04", "DEN", "2016-09-15", 540.50, 001, 'RTE02'),
(514, "DL", "MSP","2016-09-04", "DFW", "2016-09-15", 600.50, 005, 'RTE02'),
(413, "UA", "SFO","2016-09-05", "ORD", "2016-09-15", 570.50, 004, 'RTE01'),
(114, "SW", "SFO","2016-09-05", "ORD", "2016-09-15", 400.50, 001, 'RTE03'),
(515, "DL", "MSP","2016-09-06", "LAS", "2016-09-14", 410.50, 005, 'RTE04'),
(313, "AA", "MSP","2016-09-06", "LAS", "2016-09-14", 395.50, 003, 'RTE04'),
(212, "SC", "MSP","2016-09-06", "LAS", "2016-09-14", 350.50, 002, 'RTE04'),
(516, "DL", "MSP","2016-09-10", "MCO", "2016-09-20", 580.50, 002, 'RTE03'),
(416, "UA", "MSP","2016-09-10", "MCO", "2016-09-20", 470.50, 002, 'RTE03'),
(315, "AA", "MSP","2016-09-05", "MCO", "2016-09-20", 470.50, 002, 'RTE03'),
(115, "SW", "MSP","2016-09-05", "MCO", "2016-09-20", 410.50, 002, 'RTE03'),
(214, "SC", "MSP","2016-09-05", "MCO", "2016-09-20", 400.50, 002, 'RTE03'),
(215, "SC", "MSP","2016-10-05", "LAX", "2016-10-10", 410.50, 002, 'RTE03'),
(517, "DL", "MSP","2016-10-05", "LAX", "2016-09-10", 520.50, 002, 'RTE03'),
(415, "UA", "MSP","2016-10-05", "LAX", "2016-10-15", 400.50, 002, 'RTE03');

insert into Fare values
('B1', "Business Class", 'RTE01'),
('B2', "Business Class", 'RTE02'),
('B3', "Business Class", 'RTE03'),
('B4', "Business Class", 'RTE04'),
('F1', "First Class", 'RTE01'),
('F2', "First Class", 'RTE02'),
('F3', "First Class", 'RTE03'),
('F4', "First Class", 'RTE04'),
('E1', "Economy Class", 'RTE01'),
('E2', "Economy Class", 'RTE02'),
('E3', "Economy Class", 'RTE03'),
('E4', "Economy Class", 'RTE04');

insert into TicketInfo values
('DL501', "Taylor", 'B0011', 'B1', 511),
('AA300', "Smith",   'B0012',  'E2', 311),
('SW100', "Jeffries", 'B0013', 'F1', 113),
('UA400', "Hassan", 'B0014', 'E3', 414),
('SC200', "Mohammad", 'B0015', 'B2', 212);
```

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`flghtreservation`.`ticketinfo`, CONSTRAINT
>   `ticketinfo_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Flight_no`) REFERENCES `flights`
>   (`Flight_no`))

I have looked at the data type assigned to "Flight_no" and they are the same, I do not see any where there might not be a match. I know I am missing something, but cannot for the last two days of combing through this site figure out what. So I need help and I need it quickly.

Many thanks to all for taking time to read through this and assist.

Answer (score 0):

There is a record in flights table missing for flight number 311 which is referenced in the second row of TicketInfo

```
('AA300', "Smith",   'B0012',  'E2', 311)
```

Comment: @ Jen. Many thanks. I knew it was something that was right there staring at me in the face - but could not figure it out!  Thanks again
!

Comment: @zimara1 If it helps feel free to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Flight numbers must exist in the Flights table before it is used when adding to the TicketInfo table.

The error is in this line:

> ('AA300', "Smith",   'B0012',  'E2', 311),

Comment: @ Braids Constance - thank you so much. I changed the flight number in the ticketinfo table from 311 to 312 (which was on the flights table) and it worked. Many thanks man!!

Comment: @zimara1 You're welcome.  I'm just starting out, so if you could click the up-arrow next to ("upvote") my answer, I'd appreciate it.  If you can't, no stress.  I appreciate the feedback either way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is a reference problem.

You haven't inserted a record that begins with 311 in Table **Flights**, then, when you insert this *('AA300', "Smith",   'B0012',  'E2', 311)* in table **TicketInfo**... jump the exception.

Two options:

1. Add a new record that begins with 311 in Table **Flights**.
2. Change the reference 311 of this record *('AA300', "Smith",   'B0012',  'E2', 311)* of table **TicketInfo** by some that
   exists in the table **Flights**.

Comment: @ FIPS - thank you so much. I changed the flight number in the ticketinfo table from 311 to 312 (which was on the flights table) and it worked. Many thanks man!!